# D3 selection.html() , copy tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have an svg element containing a circle with tooltip applied.

I am using D3 `selection.html()` to clone this element and its contents into a new div. This works but the tooltip isn't copied across. How can I add the tooltip functionality to the new div?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>    
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Create a div containing the action button -->
    <div class="container" id = "div1">
      <button type="button"   onclick=clone() >Clone</button>       
    </div> 
    <!--Create a div that will hold the initial circle  -->
    <div class="container" id = "div2">
    </div> 
    <!--Create a div that will hold the cloned circle  -->
    <div class="container" id = "div3">
    </div>    
  </body>   
  <script>
    //Create an empty div that will hold the tooltip
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);


    //Create some data 
    var mydata=
      [{"xval":50,"yval":50,"mytooltip":"first"}
      ,{"xval":100,"yval":100,"mytooltip":"second"}
      ]
    //Append the SVG element  
    var svg = d3.select("#div2")
      .append("svg") 
      .attr("width",500)
      .attr("height", 500);
    
    //Draw a circle for each row of data
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(mydata).enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d){return d.xval})
      .attr("cy", function(d){return d.yval})
      .attr("r", 10) 
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
       div.transition()
         .duration(200)
         .style("opacity", .9);
       div.html( d.mytooltip)
       })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
       div.transition()
         .duration(500)
         .style("opacity", 0);
       });
    //Copy the SVG element this works but the tooltup functionality is not copied     
    function clone() {
      var content = d3.select("#div2").html();
      var mymod = d3.select("#div3")
      .html(content);
    }
  </script>

</html>
```

**The full problem - in case I'm going about this the wrong way**

I have a series of svg elements, one per div containing graphs whose datapoints can be filtered using user input and which feature tooltips.

I want the user to be able to enlarge an individual graph into a modal. I can do this by calling the function that draws the graph again when the modal loads, however this causes problems as I then need to re-apply the filtering.

Consequently I'm using selection.html to clone the individual graphs into the tooltip (thus inheriting the filtering). This works with the exception that the tooltip functionality isn't replicated. How can I correct this.

Comment: You're doing it in messy way, and it's clear it doesn't work because the cloned html doesn't have mouse listeners attached

Comment: `causes problems as I then need to re-apply the filtering`? What problems exactly? you already have filtered data when you're drawing small chart -- you don't need to recalculate it, just store and reuse in a sane way